# Java doesnt recognize scanner input

Tags: java, string, input, while-loop, java.util.scanner

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SimCompanies {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);

        boolean x=true;
        String complete = new String(":fire: Buying DAILY :fire:\n");
        while (x==true) {
            String input = scanner.next();
            if (input == "0") {
                System.out.println(complete);
                x=false;
            }
            else {
                complete += extend(input);
            }
        }
}

public static String extend(String a) {
        return new String( 
    ":" + a + ": " + ":" + a + ": " + ":" + a + ": " + ":" + a + ": \n" );
        
    }
```

I want to write a programme that works with an input. For every input in a new line it shall take the input and do the function "extend". I tried much and I saw that it works well with the function ( so it does everything properly with the input, no matter how many inputs I have). But I want to stopp the programme when I am writing "0". But the programme doesnt see that I am writing "0". It just always goes into the else-statement but never goes into the if-statement.
It is important that at the end everything should be printed out. So what am I doing wrong?

I want this at the end (input: Satellite, Jet)

```
:fire: Buying DAILY :fire:
:Satellite: :Satellite: :Satellite: :Satellite:
:Jet: :Jet: :Jet: :Jet:
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are trying to compare not the string content, but its instance reference. What you want is instead compare the string value.

Modify the `if` statement in the `while` loop as follow is a possible solution to fix the problem:

```
while (x==true) {
    String input = scanner.next();
    if (input.equals("0")) {
        System.out.println(complete);
        x=false;
    }
    else {
        complete += extend(input);
    }
}
```

or using:

```
if (input.compareTo("0") == 0) {
```

An example of input/output will be:

```
fire
Satellite
Jet
0
:fire: Buying DAILY :fire:
:fire: :fire: :fire: :fire: 
:Satellite: :Satellite: :Satellite: :Satellite: 
:Jet: :Jet: :Jet: :Jet:
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have never seen compareTo() but it works.

Answer (score -1):

Strings aren't primitive so you cannot use the equality operator (==) to compare with another string.

To compare 2 strings, simply use the .equals() method that is already provided as part of the String API in Java.

i.e.

```
input.equals("0")
```